# Compound random variables -- expected value

Tags: probability-theory

Let $N$ be a discrete random variable such that for $n=0,1,2,...$ $$ \mathbb{P}(N=n)=(n+1)(3/4)^2(1/4)^n $$ Let $N, X_{1},X_{2},...$ be indepedent random variables; $\mathbb{P}(X_{i}=1)=1-\mathbb{P}(X_{i}=0)=p$

Now define $N_{1}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}X_{i}$, if $N>0$ and $N_{1}=0$ for $N=0$. Let $N_{0}=N-N_{1}$. Find
$$\mathbb{E}[\frac{N_{1}}{N_{0}+1}] $$

I suppose the first step is to use the law of total probability, but what next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $n\geqslant0$, let $U_n=\mathbb E\left[\frac{N_1}{N_0+1}\mid N=n\right]$, then $U_n=n\mathbb E\left[\frac{X_1}{N_0+1}\mid N=n\right]$ by symmetry, hence $U_n=np\mathbb E\left[\frac1{N_0+1}\mid X_1=1,N=n\right]=npV_n$ with $V_n=\mathbb E\left[\frac1{N_0+1}\mid N=n-1\right]$.

Conditionally on $N=n-1$, $N_0$ is binomial $(n-1,1-p)$ hence, by definition, $V_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k}(1-p)^kp^{n-1-k}\frac1{k+1}$. Using ${n-1\choose k}\frac1{k+1}=\frac1n{n\choose k+1}$, one gets 
$$
V_n=\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{n\choose k+1}(1-p)^{k+1}p^{n-(k+1)}\frac1{1-p}=\frac1n\frac{1-p^n}{1-p}.
$$
Finally, $U_n=p\frac{1-p^n}{1-p}$, hence
$$
\mathbb E\left[\frac{N_1}{N_0+1}\right]=\frac{p}{1-p}(1-\mathbb E[p^N]),
$$
and surely you can compute $\mathbb E[p^N]$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have a question, though. Could you explain briefly why $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{N_{0}+1}|X_{1}=1,N=n]=\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{N_{0}+1}|N=n-1]$? Intuitively, this seems obvious to me, but I'd still appreciate a more formal justification.

Comment: Conditionally on $[X_1=1,N=n]$, $N_0=\sum\limits_{k=2}^n(1-X_k)$ is distributed as $N_0=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-X_k)$ unconditionally, that is, as $N_0$ conditionally on $[N=n-1]$.